# Specifying per process redirect for torchrun

Tags: pytorch

I'm using torchrun to launch multi-node training using:

`torchrun --nnodes=2 --nproc-per-node=8 ... --logdir=/path`

How can I ask for a separate stdout and stderr per process with a specific file format i.e. %rank.out and %rank.err? Thanks!